# PHP Login code doesn't work on web server, only works on local

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have a jQuery application that uses `JSONP` to communicate between the javascript(client) and PHP(server) doing Cross-Domain Requests.

I'm trying to validate a Login, decrypting the password(previously hashed) using the function `password_verify`.

The code works fine when I'm testing in the local server, but doesn't work on the web. It gets the following error in the console:

[image: Error]

[image: Internal Server Error]
Any suggestions?

Code:

Javascript - Ajax Requisition:

```
//When I submit the form, throws the requisition
$('form[name=form-login]').submit( function(){  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain:true,
        //url with callback, needed for JSONP
        url: 'http://www.my-url.com/my_apis/my_login_file.php?callback=?',  
        dataType:'jsonp',//jsonp, to Cross-Domain Requests
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            //just display a text for the user
            $('#warning').text("Checking identity...");
        }

    }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);

            if ((data.status == "OK") ){

              //if data is ok, log in normally

            }
            else if (data.status == "n"){
                //alert('Wrong credentials!');
                $('#warning').text("Invalid Login. Please try again.");
                setTimeout( function() {$('#warning').slideUp('fast');}  ,2200);

            }
            else {
                alert('Error');
            }
        })
    .fail(function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Error in the process');
            console.log(data, textStatus, errorThrown); 
        });

   return false; 
});
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:','http://myurl.com');
  header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8');

  require("connection_to_database.php");


   $usuario = $_GET['usuario'];
   $senha = $_GET['senha'];

   $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT senha FROM login_new WHERE nome = :usuario");

   $sql->bindValue(":usuario",$usuario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->execute();


   $ln = $sql->fetchColumn();// saves the found result
   $n = $sql->rowCount();



    if ($n>0){ // if has more than 1 row
       if ( password_verify($senha, $ln) =  ) { //verify the hash of the password   
           $retorno['status'] = "OK"; 
           echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno).')';

       }else{
            $retorno['status'] = "n";
            echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno).')';

       }
    }else{
   $retorno['status'] = "n";
       echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno).')';
}
```

Comment: What do you seen in the console from the `console.log(data, textStatus, errorThrown);` line?

Comment: Whats the error log show?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see nothing, because the requisition doesn't thrown the error of the `.fail` clause. It's like it is sucessful, reaching the `.done` clause, but instead of running the request correctly and returning the answer,  the error messages(images that I uploaded) appear.

Comment: That's not possible as it's returning a 500 error. The `done()` callback will only fire when a `200 OK` response is returned. Are you sure it's this AJAX request that's causing the error in the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but the only thing that appears in my console it's the first image that I uploaded, the one in red with the 'GET'. About the Ajax causing the error, I don't think it is the Ajax, but the PHP code... But I don't understand why isn't working, because when running on the local server, it works fine.

Comment: Differences in server configurations? Are you using a different version of PHP(newer) locally from the one on the web server? So that the web server PHP doesn't have all the functions you are using? password_verify() f.ex is PHP 5.5+, unless you are loading extra packages for supporting older versions.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo  I think you're right. I just re-checked my Web Server version and it's PHP 5.45. According to official PHP docs, `password_hash` and `password_verify` are only for PHP 5.5 or above. I just found this: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat that does the compatibility for older versions. I will try and post  the result here.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone that helped.

The problem was that, while my local server was `PHP 7.0.5`, my web server was using `PHP 5.4`, that doesn't have support for `password_hash` or `password_verify`.

I solved by using [this compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for older versions of `PHP` (< 5.5 ), that gives the support to use both `password_hash` and `password_verify`